# How to get specific version from tfs based on Time?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

Consider I have created a file at time feb 6 12pm and I edited the same file at time 12 30 on the same day.. Further i Edited the same file at time 1pm..

But when i go to get specific version I'm not able to get the list of the options of the versions. I'm getting the latest time stamp in the date picker box. Right now I'm using Visual studios 2008. I want to have options of picking the versions based on time. 
Please help me through this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose "Changeset" instead of "Date" in Get dialog, click on "...", click "Find" and you will get a list with all changes, including the timestamps they were created on. You can then choose the one you want to get.

If you want to get specific by Date you will have to specify the exact date, Team Explorer will not present you with a list of possible dates. Imho this option is not that useful, you're usually better off getting by changesets.